# PHP regex, extracting characters between specified characters

Tags: php, regex, split, extract

I cannot for the life of me seem to be able to figure out how I extract characters between characters.

Consider this string,

```
  $string = "sometext/#a=10/#b=25/moretext";
```

What I would like to do is extract the values of "a" and "b" (10 and 25)

So essentially what I want to do is find "#a=" and grab everything before the following /, then do the same for b. Can anyone tell me how this can be accomplished?

Also if anyone knows any solid regex tutorials they can recommend I'd very much appreciate it, I've checked nettuts, w3schools, and php.net which all have good ones but any other recommendations would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php

$string = "sometext/#a=10/#b=25/moretext/#varname=Hello World/evenmoretext/";

$matchcount = preg_match_all('@#([^=]+)=([^/]*)/@', $string, $matches);

for ($i = 0; $i < $matchcount; ++$i) {
    echo "{$matches[1][$i]} = {$matches[2][$i]}\n";
}
```

Output:

> a = 10
>   b = 25
>   varname = Hello World

A long time ago I found the site http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to be helpful and it had good information.  You may find that a GUI program for testing regular expressions can be helpful as they can show matches in real time as you type an expression.  An example that comes to mind is Regex Buddy, but this costs money.  This [online regex tester](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) looked pretty promising as well.

Comment: I need to extract absolutely everything between the characters as is, it could even be symbols. Would that method still work?

Comment: Yes, the `([^/]*)` says to keep matching anything *except* a `/` so it will match any characters and keep going until it sees `/`

Comment: To make it more robust, I changed the first part of the regex to match any characters up to the `=` sign so now the part before the `=` can be pretty much anything.

Comment: @Ian This answer is actually better than mine, the only thing I did differently is to use the `for` loop to parse the result to an associative array, but actually this expression is better - as drew says, more robust. You can easily drop the last little section of my code into this to get the same data structure out the other end.

Comment: ...thank you, I'll reselect this as the best answer and change the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "sometext/#a=10/#b=25/moretext";
$expr = '@#([a-z]+)=(.+?)/@';
$count = preg_match_all($expr, $string, $matches);

$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $result[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sexpju)

If you really want to get to grips with the nuts and bolts of regex, the best resource I can recommend is http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thank you, this is the method I'll probably end up using. I'll definitely check out that site too.